# Rails - select tag helper - display two column values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails guides

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#option-tags-from-a-collection-of-arbitrary-objects

we can show a select box with city name as options using the below

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(City.all, :id, :name) %>
```

Now my select box has below options:

- Melbourne
- London

I need to display options with city name,country in select box. How can I do this ?

Like this

- Melbournee,Australia
- London, England

have country_id in cities table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should implement proper method in `City` model, for example: `name_with_country`:

```
def name_with_country
  "#{name}, #{country.name}"
end
```

second, you should use this method and include `country` in your `cities` query to avoid N + 1 problem:

```
<%= options_from_collection_for_select(City.includes(:country), :id, :name_with_country) %>
```

Comment: @rails007 did you try it? Did it help?